Let's change the temporary logo from "Cn" to 漢?
Time to change "Cn" to 漢?
The story so far...

In Chinese Language temporary logo, droooze suggested we talk about replacing "Cn" with something more appropriate.  People gave suggestions.
I gathered the suggestions from that post (the ones I considered feasible), and created a "voting booth" here Chinese Language temporary logo --- can we vote?  The current results are:

漢 -- 6 7 votes
永 -- 2 votes (adding my upvote; I can't vote on my own post)
汉 -- 1 vote
夏 -- 0 votes

Nobody downvoted any of these, which I feel indicates: we could choose any of these and it would be better than the current "Cn".  This is also my opinion.

So, let's do it...
Question: Let's change the temporary logo from "Cn" to 漢?
If someone feels like we need more time to vote (or something else I haven't foreseen), please say so and we can "pause" this thread.  It's been over a month now, and I find it hard to believe that people are going to come along and knock 漢 from the top.  And even if that did happen, I don't see them objecting to using 漢.  (It was also suggested 7-8 years ago.)
Note: Chinese (traditional), not Japanese
Importantly, 漢 (漢, 漢) may not display the same on your screen vs. my screen.

For maximum compatibility, we might consider using U+FA47 CJK COMPATIBILITY IDEOGRAPH-FA47 漢 instead of the standard U+6F22 CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-6F22 漢. Otherwise, the top right component of the character will appear incorrectly as 艹 instead of 廿, if the user displays the character with a Japanese font. – droooze Oct 27 at 13:47

I believe the icons/logos are images, and not actual unicode characters (see: meta.SE).  So, here's some mock ups of what it should look like:



New:











I find it a bit strange how 永 was the most upvoted suggestion in the original discussion thread but didn't receive much support in the polling question. It looks to me like the CSE community supports 漢 while external users favour 永 more. I agree with 永 as a back-up choice pending on how the logo will turn out, as I have a feeling that the font size used will be far too small for 漢 to appear legible.

It's indeed possible 漢 is illegible at such small resolution.  I guess we'll find out.  (I like 永 because of it's simplicity and originality.  It's like how Pleco uses 魚, which has nothing to do with dictionaries, etc.)

As I mentioned on the original thread, among people familiar with East Asian culture or language, 永 strikes immediately as a reference to calligraphy. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_Principles_of_Yong) this is why I wasn't immediately enthralled with the idea; although I would consider Chinese character calligraphy as on-topic, we are not primarily a site for asking questions on Chinese calligraphy.

Thank you all for your patience. This design has been changed and should be visible on the site once the update is completed (hopefully later today).
... And it's live! Congrats!

It looks so cool (:  Hahaha, thanks!

Thanks! It looks really good! I've noticed that the icon on "Browse all StackExchange sites" and my StackExchange profile do not reflect the change yet (still says "Cn"), will this change at a later date?

@droooze Those get cached more heavily (since they don't change often). Can you check in with me in a week if it's still the older version?

Thanks, will do

Yeah, let's do it. We've been letting this drag on for long enough already.

Okay, so, I've reached out to @catija and referred her to this post. Now we can wait and see what happens.

Here it is hitting the Hot Network Questions list!  It's a thing of beauty.

Now we can sit back and appreciate (欣赏) it.  (:

errr . . . may i suggest the 漢 (u+6f22) in seal script (篆書), as "graphic", something like these:




imo, a han-chinese character in seal script is, more authoritative and formal.

We can’t do this. The suggested logo is only temporary, and has to be generated from text, until the site graduation is complete and we have a full website theme. After that, we can get a seal script logo.

oh :( i see. so, maybe “do it later”
